# GeoIP and Ontario Canada?

Tags: .htaccess, restrict, geoip

I've had several users from Ontario, Canada contact me and saying they can't access my site.  Using the GeoIP Module in my htaccess file I have allowed Canada.  Any idea what might be causing this?

Here's my entry in the htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
    GeoIPEnable On

    # US - United States
    # CA - Canada

    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry
    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CA AllowCountry

    Deny from all
    Allow from env=AllowCountry

</IfModule>
```

The interesting thing is if I do the opposite, they have access like so:

```
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
    GeoIPEnable On

    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE NG BlockCountry
    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE RO BlockCountry
    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE VN BlockCountry
    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE GH BlockCountry
    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE SN BlockCountry
    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE TN BlockCountry
    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE IN BlockCountry
    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE KE BlockCountry

    Deny from env=BlockCountry

</IfModule>
```

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: The module may not be recognizing them as coming from Canada. It's not a foolproof method.

Comment: Are there better ways to allow/restrict countries access to a site?

Comment: Not really, no... I guess blacklisting countries you have problems with will be the approach with less false positives though. If you *need* to do this, I would go with that

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust geographical informations picked up by IP addresses. There are high possibilities that the information associated to the IP is not valid or get outdated quickly.
IP addresses can be dynamically routed, the client user could come via a proxy or tunnel, and so on.

Comment: I need to restrict certain countries because of content SPAM and/or fake profiles.

Comment: @Paul well, the client's IP address it's just a hint, don't trust it too much. http://www.maxmind.com/app/faq#accurate - That approach could create false positives.